# adding object to the beginning of a state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I update and add object to the beginning of state array? (`pop` instead of `push`) I know how to add it to the end using this method:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  arr: [...prevState.arr, newelement]
}))
```

how am I adding it to the beginning?

Comment: I believe `unshift()` mutates the array calling it, so it's not a good choice for React. See the answers below

Comment: Welp never mind, the person removed their comment. But I'll leave my comment here, since it's a good point to keep in mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the order:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  arr: [newElement, ...prevState.arr ]
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly the same as adding to the end with spread, just reverse the order:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    arr: [newelement, ...prevState.arr]
}))
```